# Como recibo una lista de objetos en Webmethod usando AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net, webforms

disculpen estoy batallando un poco con lo siguiente, quiero mandar atravez de ajax una lista de objetos a mi web method pero este no recibe info:

```
 var jsonObj = [];
    $.each(sel, function (index, object) {
        var e = 0;
        var ProyectosId = object["ProyectoId"];
        for (var en in enc) {
            var EncuestasId = enc[en];
            item = {
                "EncuestasId": EncuestasId,
                "ProyectosId": ProyectosId,
                "created": null,
                "updated": null,
                "deleted": null
            }
            jsonObj.push(item);
            e++;
        }
    });
    var j = { dat: { rel: jsonObj } };
```

Mi Ajax es el siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/cargarRelacion",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(j),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            OnSuccess(response);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("no entro");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Sepa que chingados paso");
        }
    });
```

Y mi webmethod:

[WebMethod]
public static void cargarRelacion(List dat){

```
    List<String> col = new List<string>();
    DataTable dt = MyExtensions.ToDataTable(dat);
    DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
    dtt.Columns.Add("EncuestasId", typeof(int));
    dtt.Columns.Add("ProyectosId", typeof(int));
    dtt.Columns.Add("created", typeof(DateTime));
    dtt.Columns.Add("updated", typeof(DateTime));
    dtt.Columns.Add("deleted", typeof(DateTime));
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        dtt.Rows[dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr)][dt.Columns["EncuestasId"]] = Convert.ToInt32(dr.ToString());
        dtt.Rows[dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr)][dt.Columns["ProyectosId"]] = Convert.ToInt32(dr.ToString());
    }
    SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con2"].ConnectionString);
    SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(c);
    s.DestinationTableName = "EncuestasProyectos";//Selecciona la tabla de destino
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con2"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            //Lee los nombres de las columnas
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE COLUMN_NAME <> 'RowID' AND TABLE_NAME = 'EncuestasProyectos' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION";
            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //Agrega los nombre de las columnas a una lista
                    col.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    int t = col.Count;//Obtiene el numero de columnas
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        //Asigna el nombre de las columnas origen y destino en relación al nombre de las columnas en la BD   que se guardaron en la lista col             
        s.ColumnMappings.Add(col[i], col[i]);
    }
    //s.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
    //c.Open();
    //s.WriteToServer(dtt);
    //col.Clear();
    //c.Close();
}
```

Lo comentado es porque aun no lo meto en producción, aqui adjunto dos imagenes, la primera muestra loq ue recibe el WebMethod y la segunda lo que envia el Ajax:

[image: Aqui esta lo que trae almecenado el webmethod]

[image: Y esto es lo que mi Ajax esta recibiendo]

No se que me falte pero ya me duele la cabeza de intentarlo sin preguntar así que acudo pidiendo ayuda, muchísimas gracias de antemanos por la atención y el apoyo, saludos.

Comment: Prueba de la siguiente forma: cambia el tipo de datos del webmethod como object: *CargaRelacion(object dat)* luego en ese metodo agregas *JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();*
*var lista = (List<string>)jss.Deserialize(dat.ToString(),typeof(List<string>))* y en el ajax pasas:   *options.data = JSON.stringify({ dat: JSON.stringify(jsonObj)})*. Es importante que el tipo coincida con lo que recibe. He puesto List<string> como ejemplo, creo que el tipo de datos es otro. En la variable lista deberias tener los datos que pasaste.